# Why can't I change the active selected bone?

Tags: armature, selection-tools

I am editing an armature object in Edit mode. I have the upper bone selected, and want to select the lower one.

[image: Upper selected]

To my knowledge, the last item selected should become the "active" selection. Once I shift-click the lower, it should become active and highlighted yellow. Instead, I get this after shift-clicking.

[image: Both selected]

Both are selected but the upper is still active. I can't seem to make the lower active. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you upload the blender file so that we can get a better idea of what might be going on?  Thanks.

Comment: You're idea of selecting and active objects sounds correct. Did you make sure to select the objects in the **3D Viewport** and ***not*** in the *Outliner*?

Comment: @Leander yes, this is via mouse-selection in the viewport. The .blend file is [here](https://gist.github.com/roysc/85a0a1daa772985e29165c4202e57c03), containing just two bones. On Blender 2.82, I can only make bone "two" active; "one" always stays orange